# how do I fix a nodejs package dependency issue?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a nodejs package I wish to use - "redis-connect". This is dependent on "hiredis" but seems to be locked at 0.1.7 which does not compile. I am using 7.2.0 nodejs with npm 4.0.3 - problem with node-gyp rebuild. However, hiredis@0.5.0 compiles fine and installs. What's best practise for fixing this dependency so I can install and use redis-connect with hiredis@0.5.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "best practice" for something like this. You just have to submit a pull request to the project and convince the maintainer to accept the PR and publish a new version afterwards.

Otherwise you will need to just fork the project and reference that fork (instead of the original project by its name on npm) in your dependencies.